# Share two Dropbox accounts?

Tags: macos, dropbox

How can I synchronize on my computer two different dropbox accounts?

I share one privately and one with my office.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Sorry forgot that: OSX

Comment: How about doing this on Windows?

Comment: An easier, less hacky way would be to share a folder from your work dropbox to your personal one. It will use up more space, but is fully supported and may be easier to keep track of as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [extensive tutorial here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/run-multiple-dropbox-accounts-simultaneously-mac/) from the guys at *MakeUseOf.* I shall write it here though:

1. Open the Terminal (again)
2. Type (or just copy and paste) this command:
   `bash`

Hit enter and insert the next command line:

```
$ HOME=$HOME/.dropbox-alt /Applications/Dropbox.app/Contents/MacOS/Dropbox &
```

It should now look like:

[image]

- A new Dropbox icon will appear in the menubar.

[image]

- A Dropbox account setup window will also pop up. Follow the setup
  steps.

[image]

- At the last setup step, tick the option to choose your own location of Dropbox folder. Hit the “Change” button to determine the location.

[image]

- After the setup process complete, you can close the terminal. Theoretically, the extra Dropbox instances will also be closed, but in my experiment it remained in the menubar.

**If you wish to add it as a startup item, the tutorial also shows that.**